# Must declare scalar variable with update percentage

Tags: sql-server

I am updating the articles by a stored procedure but I get an error. No idea how to solve my problem. I am totally new to database programming. Please help me.

This is my code:

```
create procedure p_rabatt 
    (@articleID int, 
     @precentage int)
as
    update Artikel
    set Preis = Preis * (1 + (@percentage / 100)) 
    where ArtikelCode = @articleID
```

Thanks for your gently feedback, guys!

[image: table error]

Comment: TYPO: you declare precentage in the header but you type percentage in the UPDATE statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@precentage`  parameter name is not the same as `@percentage`

Comment: ohhh thanks, when some one works a lot on pc